# How to show only current parent product category with subcategories and hide others in widget on the product category page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For example, there are 2 different catalogs - men and women (clothes).

There is a widget in sidebar.

Is it possible to hide 'men' category with its child subcategories in all 'women' category pages and subcategory pages, and the same  in 'men' catalog in all parent categories and child subcategories hide all from 'women'? From product cat widget.

I tried conditions like

```
if( has_term(267, 'product_cat' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'organicweb_exclude_widget_category' );
    function organicweb_exclude_widget_category( $args ) {
    // Enter the id of the category you want to exclude in place of '30'
            $args['exclude'] = array('262' );
            return $args;
    }
} 


if( is_product_category( array( '267',) ) ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'organicweb_exclude_widget_category' );
    function organicweb_exclude_widget_category( $args ) {
    // Enter the id of the category you want to exclude in place of '30'
            $args['exclude'] = array('262' );
            return $args;
    }
}
```

The filter works without 'if///{}', hides excluded category from widget at all, but not with if.
I start to think that the simplest way is to hide  them using css(body class+parent li id), but maybe it is a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'product_cat'    => 'your-cat-name'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Also this article will help you https://www.codecheef.org/article/how-to-display-category-wise-product-in-woocommerce

Thank you